# Spree - Override checkout_controller methods

Tags: overriding, checkout, spree

I need to override the method [rescue_from_spree_gateway_error](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/frontend/app/controllers/spree/checkout_controller.rb#L149) from the controller [checkout_controller.rb](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/frontend/app/controllers/spree/checkout_controller.rb)

My gateway is returning this:

```
Gateway Error   --- !ruby/object:ActiveMerchant::Billing::Response params:   success: false   order_status:    message: Autoriza��o negada   amount:    order:    transaction:  message: Autoriza��o negada success: false test: false authorization:  fraud_review:  avs_result:   code:    message:    street_match:    postal_match:  cvv_result:   code:    message:
```

This is my override, at `/app/controllers/checkout_controller_decorator.rb`

```
module Spree
  CheckoutController.class_eval do
    def rescue_from_spree_gateway_error(error)
      puts "==========================================="
      flash[:error] = error.message
      render :edit
    end
  end
end
```

I have added the `puts` so I could see it on the console but it was not printed.

I also have added another `puts` above the method declaration and it prints out when I start the server:

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.13 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
!!!!!THIS IS ABOVE THE METHOD!!!!! [2013-09-05 16:33:31] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1 [2013-09-05 16:33:31] INFO  ruby 1.9.3 (2013-06-27) [x86_64-linux] [2013-09-05 16:33:31] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=21635 port=3000
```

So it shows me that the class is loaded but the method is never called like the error returned above by the `ActiveMerchant::Billing::Response` is not a Gateway Error.

The `checkout_controller` has this line calling the method when a `GatewayError` happens:

```
rescue_from Spree::Core::GatewayError, :with => :rescue_from_spree_gateway_error
```

Comment: Maybe that's because method in core is without arguments and your does have arg?

Comment: I really don't know, I was following one suggestion from a user on the mail group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/spree-user/rRcIoDs-9Dc

Comment: @zrl3dx I just tried it, removed the argument and hard coded the message `flash[:error] = "Not authorized"`, nothing happened =/

Comment: Try putting it into `app/controllers/spree` instead of `app/controllers`, AFAIK decorators' functionality is strictly connected with path (and filename too).

Comment: @zrl3dx no success =/

Comment: Then try fullpath from new spree version, i.e. `spree/frontend/app/controllers/spree`.

Comment: @zrl3dx no success =/

Comment: @zrl3dx if you have the time, can you go to chat?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36938/discussion-between-zrl3dx-and-gerep)

Comment: @zrl3dx Have you checked the new answer?

Comment: @zrl3dx I found the problem =) Thanks for the great help ;)

Comment: Glad you resolved it ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Spree version is 2.0.3.

To make this work I had to override two files, creating them at:

`app/controllers/checkout_controller_decorator.rb`

`app/models/order_decorator.rb`

The `checkout_controller_decorator.rb` code:

```
module Spree
  CheckoutController.class_eval do
    def update
      if @order.update_attributes(object_params)
        fire_event('spree.checkout.update')
        return if after_update_attributes
        unless @order.next
          flash[:error] = @order.errors[:base].join("\n")
          redirect_to checkout_state_path(@order.state) and return
        end
        if @order.completed?
          session[:order_id] = nil
          flash.notice = Spree.t(:order_processed_successfully)
          flash[:commerce_tracking] = "nothing special"
          redirect_to completion_route
        else
          redirect_to checkout_state_path(@order.state)
        end
      else
        render :edit
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And the `order_decorator.rb` code:

```
module Spree
  Order.class_eval do

    def process_payments!
      if pending_payments.empty?
        raise Core::GatewayError.new Spree.t(:no_pending_payments)
      else
        pending_payments.each do |payment|
          break if payment_total >= total

          payment.process!

          if payment.completed?
            self.payment_total += payment.amount
          end
        end
      end
      rescue Core::GatewayError => e
        result = !!Spree::Config[:allow_checkout_on_gateway_error]
        errors.add(:base, e.message) and return result
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The problem is with the version `2.0.3` so I had to update those two files with the ones from the version `2.0.4` and the problem is solved =)

Answer (score 2):

The exception you're trying to catch is being caught earlier.  Almost certainly here:

https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/v2.0.4/core/app/models/spree/order.rb#L443

You'll need to override that function to add the logic that you're looking for.